# NSolve with NIntegrate returns empty list

Tags: equation-solving

I have defined a function $p\left[x,V\right]$

```
p[x_,V_]:= (2/Sqrt[Pi V^2]) Exp[-x^2 / V^2]
```

just a Gaussian, normalised such that integrating over all positive x I get 1.

I have functions

```
cdf[V_,lim_]:= NIntegrate[p[x,V],{x,0,lim}]
median[V_]:=FindRoot[cdf[V,lim]==0.5,{lim,1.}]
```

which calculates the median of $p[x,V]$.

I would now like to write a function which takes a number $\alpha$ as input, and returns the variance $V$ for which $median[V] = \alpha$.  I do this as follows

```
fun[α_]:=NSolve[median[V]==α,V]
```

This function however only returns empty lists $\{ \}$, even when I can verify that a solution exists (by e.g. plotting median[V], or "manually" finding the correct $V$).

How should I rewrite my functions to find the $V$ such that $median[V] = \alpha$ ?

Comment: Suggest that you add the code for `p[x]`

Comment: Done, thanks. This is the simplest case, but still exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition for the probability density function is:

```
p[x_, variance_] := 2/Sqrt[π variance^2] Exp[-x^2/variance^2]
```

Here is a plot with different variance parameters.

```
Plot[{p[x, 0.2], p[x, 0.4], p[x, 0.6], p[x, 0.8], p[x, 1.0]},
  {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the definition of the cumulative distribution function. We force the input arguments to be numerical to facilitate subsequent processing in `FindRoot` (avoids error messages).

```
cdf[variance_ /; variance > 0, limit_ /; limit > 0] := 
 NIntegrate[p[x, variance], {x, 0, limit}]
```

We are interested in the correlation between the variance and the `x` value corresponding to `cdf = 0.5`.

Here is a graph of it with different variance parameters.

```
Show[
 Plot[{cdf[0.2, x], cdf[0.4, x], cdf[0.6, x], cdf[0.8, x], 
   cdf[1.0, x]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}],
 Plot[0.5, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Black]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is a table of variance values and the corresponding `x` value where the `cdf` is 0.5.

```
median[variance_] := FindRoot[cdf[variance, limit] == 0.5, {limit, 0.2}]

varianceData = 
 Table[{limit /. median[variance], variance}, {variance, 0.2, 1, 0.2}]
(* {{0.0953873, 0.2}, {0.190775, 0.4}, {0.286162, 
  0.6}, {0.381549, 0.8}, {0.476936, 1.}} *)
```

We superimpose it on our plot.

```
Show[
 Plot[{cdf[0.2, x], cdf[0.4, x], cdf[0.6, x], cdf[0.8, x], 
   cdf[1.0, x]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}],
 Plot[0.5, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Black],
 ListPlot[
  Transpose@Join[{varianceData[[All, 1]]}, {ConstantArray[0.5, 5]}],
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.025], Red}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The question is, given a particular `x = α`, what is the corresponding variance?

That can be solved using the same procedure as `median` but swapping the variable and parameter.

```
fun[α_] := FindRoot[cdf[variance, α] == 0.5, {variance, 0.2}]
```

Let's test it by using as inputs the `limit` value from `varianceData` and see if we get back the same variances.

```
limitData = 
 Table[{limit, variance /. fun[limit]},
   {limit, varianceData[[All, 1]]}]

(* {{0.0953873, 0.2}, {0.190775, 0.4}, {0.286162, 
  0.6}, {0.381549, -0.8}, {0.476936, -1.}} *)
```

Sure enough, seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry,as a novice I'm no allowed to comment your question:

The definition of your median-function seems to be wrong, because the parameter lim is not defined!

Perhaps

```
median[V_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[cdf[V, lim] == 0.5, {lim, 1.}]
```

is the function you're looking for.

In this definition you find also the appendix _?NumericQ, which helps to handle purely numerical functions like the first one(NIntegrate)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from `_?NumericQ` to quiet some unimportant error, the big error is the missing `lim /. ...` in `median[]`.  `FindRoot` returns a [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html), which needs to be converted to a numeric value.

```
ClearAll[p, cdf, fun, median];
p[x_, V_] := (2/Sqrt[Pi V^2]) Exp[-x^2/V^2]
cdf[V_?NumericQ, lim_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[p[x, V], {x, 0, lim}]
median[V_?NumericQ] := lim /. FindRoot[cdf[V, lim] == 0.5, {lim, 1.}]
fun[α_] := NSolve[median[V] == α, V]
```

Checks: Left inverse.

```
fun[0.5`]
median /@ (V /. %)
```

> NSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

```
(*  {{V -> 1.04836}}  <-- fun[0.5] *)

(*  {0.5}             <-- {median[V /. fun[0.5]]} *)
```

Right inverse.

```
median[1.]
fun[%]

(*  0.476936     <-- median[1.] *)
```

> NSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

```
(*  {{V -> 1.}}  <-- fun[median[1.]] *)
```

Note the use of `InverseFunction`.  Basically, `NSolve`, which is principally for analytic equations and not ones involving numerical methods, calls `InverseFunction[median, 1, 1][α]`.  So another way to define `fun` is

```
fun[α_] := InverseFunction[median, 1, 1][α]
```

Note the original `fun` returns a `Rule`, but this returns a value:

```
median[2.]
fun[%]
(*
  0.953873
  2.
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

To define your own probability distribution and make the most use of Mathematica's built-in capabilities, use [`ProbabilityDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html). Note the change from `V^2` to `V` to be **proportional** to the actual [`Variance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variance.html) of your distribution.

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[2/Sqrt[π V] Exp[-x^2/V], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> V > 0];
```

The [`DistributionParameterAssumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionParameterAssumptions.html) are the [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) specified in `ProbabilityDistribution`.

```
assume = DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist]

(* V > 0 *)

PDF[dist, x]
```

[image]

```
Assuming[assume, Integrate[PDF[dist, x], {x, 0, Infinity}]]

(* 1 *)
```

Or using the [`CDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CDF.html)

```
CDF[dist, x]
```

[image]

```
Assuming[assume, Limit[CDF[dist, x], x -> Infinity]]

(* 1 *)
```

Having used `ProbabilityDistribution`, built-in functions such as [`Mean`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html), [`Median`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Median.html), and [`Variance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variance.html) will work with your distribution. Note that the `Variance` is proportional to, but not equal to `V`

```
#[dist] & /@ {Mean, Median, Variance}
```

[image]

To find `V` corresponding to a `Median` of `α`

```
solV = Solve[Median[dist] == α, V][[1]]
```

[image]

However if you want the `Variance` corresponding to a `Median` of `α`

```
Variance[dist] /. solV
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[{V, Variance[dist]} /. solV],
 {α, 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> {Style[α, Bold, 14], None},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{V, Variance}, {.85, .4}],
 PlotLabel -> Style["V and Variance for Median[dist] == α", 14, Bold]]
```

[image]